# C/C++ Extension in VS Code - Compiler linking "_string.h" instead of "string.h"

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gcc

I am using "strcpy()" in a program and when calling it, I get a syntax warning saying

> too few arguments in invocation of of macro strcpy'

After doing some digging, I found that my compiler is linking `_string.h` from the path `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.1.sdk/usr/include/secure/_string.h` which implements a `_string.h` macro. And so far, this is on the only library I've had this issue with. (yes I am including `string.h` and not `_string.h`

It is safe to assume this is due to the C/C++ Extension for VS Code, as I did not have this problem when recreating this in vim.

Below is a screenshot from the extension when "hovering" over my usage of `strcpy()`:[image]

Has anyone else had this problem and if so, how did you fix it? And what is the difference between `_string.h` and `string.h`?

***Update:***

After looking at the `_string.h` file, line #25 has the following `# error "Never use <secure/_string.h> directly; include <string.h> instead."`, yet I am only using `string.h`

Comment: how many arguments do you have?

Comment: First of all: noone is _linking_ `_string.h` because that's a header file. Secondly, you need to show us at least how you invoke your compiler. You say you get a syntax "warning". So .... is it really a warning? Or an error? If it's an error, is it the compiler that's reporting the error or is it just VS Code yelling at you? Please try to be a bit more precise about what is actually happening.

Comment: What does your call to `strcpy()` look like, exactly?

Comment: @UniversE Well 1. the LINKER is linking the header file, 2. It's a warning since it compiles and executes, I would've said it was an error if it was an error. I also said that it was VS Code, not my compiler, that was the issue. All of which was said in the initial post.

Comment: @SteveSummit it is right below the macro declaration, `strcpy(message_arr, input_msg` this problem is not due the way I am using the function.

Comment: @koncameron no the linker only links **object files**

Comment: Please post a [mcve], including a complete C source and a command to compile it.

Comment: @koncameron No reason to be snappy. The linker is not linking header files. That's wrong. There is no such thing as a "syntax warning", but there is something that's called "syntax error" - that's why I asked. Also, an incorrect number of arguments for a function in C *is* an error (and not a warning) - so your story did not add up here. Reading between the lines, we can only _guess_ that there is either a bug or a misconfiguration of your VS Code plugin. But since you haven't posted your configuration we cannot tell you _what exactly_ you might have misconfigured.

Answer (score 2):

*_string.h* says

> Never use `<secure/_string.h>` **directly**; include `<string.h>` instead.

So it means that *string.h* includes *_string.h*